# Unable to debug WebMethod in ASPX on ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, firebug

I am trying to send a screenshot done via [`html2canvas`](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to the server using an AJAX call and the POST method, but it's not happening. When I am trying to debug the script using Firebug by setting breakpoints at the related lines, my application is not hitting the breakpoint.

Here is my client-side code (using jQuery):

```
$("#excel").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        html2canvas($("#placeholder").get(0), {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                //document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                var img = canvas.toDataURL().replace(/^data[:]image\/(png|jpg|jpeg)[;]base64,/i, "");
                $.ajax({
                    "type": "POST",
                    "url": "Default.aspx/MyMethod",
                    "data": {
                        "imageData": img //Send to WebMethod
                    }
                }).done(function (o) {
                    console.log(["Response:", o]);
                });

            }
    });
```

And this is my server-side ASPX WebMethod:

```
 [WebMethod()]
public static void MyMethod(string imageData)
{

    string fileNameWitPath = "D:/Kabir/custom_name.png";
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileNameWitPath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
        {
            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);//convert from base64
            bw.Write(data);
            bw.Close();
        }
    }
```

When I try to see it within Firebug, its status is `200 OK`. Why is this happening?

Comment: Is it correctly passing the parameter? Also check the entire url is correct and that it is not hitting somewhere else? Have you tried breakpoints at the start of the function?

Comment: @user2338488 localhost:4247/JQPlot/Default.aspx/MyMethod this is my URl and parameretrs are correct

Comment: @user2338488 I am getting error at console.log(["Response:", o]); when seen in firebug

Comment: if you look at your network tab in firebug, look for that post been called, and see what the response for that call is.

Comment: @user2338488 In my Post imageData has been passed as parameter and in the Response i am seeing my web page html contents

Comment: Try adding these parameters to the ajax call: contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",

Comment: @user2338488 On adding this $.ajax({
                        "type": "POST",
                        "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
                        "dataType": "json", 
                        "url": "Default.aspx/MyMethod",
                        "data": {
                            "imageData": img //Send to WebMethod
                        }
                    }).done(function (o) {
                        console.log(["Response:", o]);
                    });

Comment: @user2338488 On adding above i am getting error in Response and that error is ..<html>
    <head>
        <title>Unknown web method MyMethod.<br>Parameter name: methodName</title>

Comment: @Laxman Try alerting the value of img. If it is undefined that may explain why the call is failing.

Comment: @Laxman If all else is correct,try using Fiddler to check HTTP status of call or try changing url  parameter as "url": "JQPlot/Default.aspx/MyMethod".

Comment: @Ash The value of img is coming in alert box as iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAfQAAAEsCAYAAAA1u0HIAAAgAElEQVR4nO3deZAk1WHn

Comment: @Laxman Try changing url parameter as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @Ash i changed URL to "url": "JQPlot/Default.aspx/MyMethod" but its giving error 404 not foud

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid JSON:

> ```
>                 "type": "POST",
>                 "url": "Default.aspx/MyMethod",
>                 "data": {
>                     "imageData": img //Send to WebMethod
>                 }
> ```

Problem is in your canvas data, Use this one . and just replace the var img = "image"; variable to as your desire input

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#excel").on("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                //document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                var img = "image";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Default.aspx/MyMethod",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ imageData: img }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                }).done(function (o) {
                    console.log(["Response:", o]);
                });


            });
        });
```

Comment: getting error as " <title>Unknown web method MyMethod.<br>Parameter name: methodName</title>" in firebug Response

Comment: problem is in your canvas data,see my answer above and change accordingly

Comment: but its working on my side! let me add my code below as new answer

Comment: again its giving error "<title>Unknown web method MyMethod.<br>Parameter name: methodName</title>" ...what may be the other reasons of the error..Please help me Sir..May be something needs to be changed into the web.config

Comment: may be.
check your method name, make it in lowercase, and verify the name should be same . it is case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

**On your client side**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#excel").on("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                //document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                var img = "image";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Default.aspx/MyMethod",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ imageData: img }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                }).done(function (o) {
                    console.log(["Response:", o]);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <input type="button" id="excel" title="something" />
```

**On code behind**

```
 [WebMethod()]
        public static void MyMethod(string imageData)
        {

            string fileNameWitPath = "D:/Kabir/custom_name.png";
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileNameWitPath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
                {
                    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);//convert from base64
                    bw.Write(data);
                    bw.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```